# availableInputs API cannot detect Samsung headphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiosession

I am trying to direct the application sound to the headphone but it is impossible for non apple headphones because the availableInputs API returns nil.

```
NSArray *inputs = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs];
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: I am using AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord category.

Comment: Place this `[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                     withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                                           error:nil];` in `AppDelegate didFinishLaunching` method.

Comment: If you need to check more check the [Apple's Sample App](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/aurioTouch/Listings/Classes_AudioController_mm.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007770-Classes_AudioController_mm-DontLinkElementID_4)

Comment: I tried your advise but it still could not find the samsung headphone input with the API availableInputs.

Comment: There are other category and options available try others, as well as do your headphone work normally with other apps?

Comment: Thanks. I got the solution with other API named currentRoute. Apple is very interesting, one API not works for non Apple  headphones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The currentRoute API works. So I used both availableInputs and currentRoute APIs for detecting the input devices.